# Find the Length of $QP$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

Given two circles with radii $8$ and $6$ units with centers $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=12$ If $P$ is mid point of $QR$

Find Length of $QP$
[image]

My try:

I assumed $A(0,0)$ and $B(12,0)$

So the equations of circles are:

$$x^2+y^2=64$$

$$(x-12)^2+y^2=36$$

Solving above equations we get:

$$P\left(\frac{43}{6}, \frac{\sqrt{455}}{6}\right)$$

Then we can assume

$$Q(8\cos\alpha, 8\sin \alpha)$$

$$R(12+6\cos\beta,6\sin\beta)$$

Using mid point formula we get:

$$8\cos\alpha+6\cos\beta=\frac{7}{3}$$

$$8\sin\alpha+6\sin\beta=\frac{\sqrt{455}}{3}$$

Any idea here?

Comment: solve for $cos \alpha$ and $sin \alpha$ from the last 2 equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You don't need any trigonometry or analytical geometry. The following equations are quite obvious (Pythagora):

$$p^2+\frac{x^2}{4}=8^2=64\tag{1}$$

$$q^2+\frac{x^2}{4}=6^2=36\tag{2}$$

$$(p-q)^2+x^2=12^2=144\tag{3}$$

Introduce substitution: $y=\frac{x^2}{4}$ and you get:

$$p=\sqrt{64-y}\tag{4}$$

$$q=\sqrt{36-y}\tag{5}$$

$$(p-q)^2+4y=144\tag{6}$$

Replace (4) and (5) into (6):

$$(\sqrt{64-y}-\sqrt{36-y})^2+4y=144$$

$$100-2y-2\sqrt{(64-y)(36-y)}+4y=144$$

$$2y-44 = 2\sqrt{(64-y)(36-y)}$$

$$y-22=\sqrt{(64-y)(36-y)}$$

$$(y-22)^2=(64-y)(36-y)$$

$$(y-22)^2-(64-y)(36-y)=0$$

$$56y-1820=0$$

$$y=\frac{x^2}{4}=\frac{1820}{56}=\frac{65}{2}$$

$$x=\sqrt{130}$$

Comment: Are the blue dots centers of the circles?

Comment: @Umeshshankar Yes, they are.